# How to find full path of device I've connected?

Tags: devices, paths, serial-port

I have USB device, which is actually identified as serial device by Ubuntu 10.04. How can I find its full path?

```
ls -la /dev/
```

shows a lot of devices. How to choose correct one?

Answer (score 11):

Probably the simplest thing to do, but not always simple to interpret, is to run `dmesg` after inserting the device.

For a flash memory pendrive you can find something like the following

```
[39653.096626] usb-storage: device scan complete
[39653.097617] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[39653.099860] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[39653.101089] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1994752 512-byte logical blocks: (1.02 GB/974 MiB)
[39653.101588] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[39653.101592] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[39653.101595] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[39653.110832] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[39653.110839]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[39653.197706] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[39653.197712] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[39653.960873] EXT4-fs (sdb2): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
[39653.962127] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
```

where it is simple to see that two partition `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` are on the drive.

For a serial device you should find something talking about `ttyS0` or similar, corresponding to `/dev/ttyS0`.

Comment: OK, but what is the path?

Comment: don't you see sdb2? the path is /dev/sdb2

Answer (score 11):

For serial devices I tend to look in `/dev/serial/by-id`. For disks I use `/dev/disk/by-label`. If you use `ls -l` on those they'll show you where they're linked to.

Answer (score 9):

From a Terminal prompt:

```
df -h
```

You should have a screen similiar to the one attached which should give you the mount point of the USB device.

[image]

Comment: -1 that command will show disk usage when the OP has stated his device is showing up as a serial device.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all information related to a device from the built-in disk utility available in Ubuntu (called *Disks* in Ubuntu 13.04 and newer versions.).

- full path of device. (e.x. /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1)
- partition type
- serial number
- size of device and model name